# DispatchEvent from an static var in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, static, flexbuilder

Is it possible to dispatch an event from a `public static var` in Flex? I'm doing this, and Flex throws me an error:

File `board.mxml`:

```
public static var actionBar:ActionBar;

<mx:VBox>
   <ActionBar:ActionBar id="actionBar"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

File `layerMng.as`:

```
board.actionBar.dispatchEvent(...)
```

Error -> 1119: Access of possibly undefined property actionBar through a reference with static type Class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching events has nothing to do with a variable being static or not.

Try doing this way:

```
ActionBar.actionBar.dispatchEvent(...)
```

as `actionBar` is a static varible and should be preceded by the class' name

Comment: I add some source code to get a better view of my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Or you `actionBar` was not initialized; or
2. You need to access it not as an object attribute but as a class attribute, like

   `Board.actionBar.dispatchEvent(...)`

Notice the uppercase `B` of `Board`, that means its the class name not the object instance name.

**[edit]**
3. notice that your error message says **ac[c]ionBar** while you have **ac[t]ionBar**, idk if was just a typo, so just check it.

Comment: I add some source code to get a better view of my problem. Thanks.